# Problems using Whatsapp on HTC One V

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, htc-one-v

I'm facing a problem using Whatsapp. Many times if I received 2-3 pics or a large conversation on Whatsapp, the phone's title bar (where it shows date, battery status & network status) disappears automatically. Also when I open Whatsapp it opens and disappears so in that case I have to select any pic/note & select option share on Whatsapp. Then Whatsapp opens after forwarding that pic/note. I have to use the option of clear conversation and then everything becomes normal.

This is really a very irritating procedure. I don't know why this happens. Many friends of mine who use other company mobiles with the same configuration as my HTC One V don't have this type of problem. Please suggest what the problem is.

Comment: Did you try removing and then reinstalling the app?

Comment: Remove the data and then uninstall the app. Failing that report it as a bug directly to the developer!

Answer (score 1):

HTC One V users can now take the software update. HTC has provided the update for whatsapp crash. Go to Settings>About>Software Update

Answer (score 0):

Since this issue is mostly isolated to HTC devices running 4.0.4 OS or older, we have reason to believe your device may have issues with Indian languages written in Devanagari such as Hindi, Punjabi, Gujarati etc. Android only recently added Sanskrit based characters support to Android 4.3. This is likely what is causing the crash in your history. Unfortunately, this is not something that WhatsApp can resolve, the only known fix is to update your phone to a phone that supports Sanskrit languages or to ask your contacts to stop sending you messages containing Devanagari fonts.

If you have any other questions or concerns, please feel free to contact us. We would be happy to help!

Regards
Kuldeep

Answer (score -1):

Try updating HTC one v software. This will solve your issue. No need to reinstall whatsapp. You can go to Setting -> About -> Software Update -> Check now.

Answer (score -2):

If the title bar disappears, install a task killer and kill all tasks. It may help.

Comment: _How_ will it help? Using a task killer is counter-productive and generally a bad idea.